# Issue creating Premium - requiring subscription

Tags: civicontribute, premiums

When trying to add a new Premium (first one), I get the error "Please enter a Period Type" - even though the premium is a regular "product" and not a subscription.
Civi 5.31 / Drupal 7.73 / PHP 7.3

[image]

Comment: I've reproduced this on 5.31. I just added in the settings to get around temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Problem identified and fixed by @eileen with commit planned for 5.32 - https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/148